# Add floating button under listview in fragment list

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I have an application with one main activity and some fragment, every fragment is a list fragment, but, in some of them, I need to add a FloatingActionButton with a custom action, and I would like preserve the auto generated adapter for that list.
If I add the FloatingActionButton directly to the xml the list disapper, how can I add the button?

This is my fragment xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="it.ivannotarstefano.cojule.activity.PlayerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="it.ivannotarstefano.cojule.activity.PlayerFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_player" >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

And I have tried to add the FloatingActionButton in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="it.ivannotarstefano.cojule.activity.PlayerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="it.ivannotarstefano.cojule.activity.PlayerFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_player" >

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#fff700" />

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="it.ivannotarstefano.cojule.activity.PlayerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        app:backgroundTint="#fff700" />

</FrameLayout>
```